# Change fontSize for text component with function in React Native

Tags: react-native, text-styling

I am trying to adjust the font size of a text object inside a timer based on the remaining time. As there are fewer digits to display I want the text to get larger. The problem I'm having is it looks like you can't call a function in the style definition (please correct anything I misstated there, I'm trying to learn). First, the function:

```
CalculateTimeSize = ({ remainingTime }) => {
    let TimerTextSize
    if( remainingTime < 60 ) {
        TimerTextSize = 60
    } else if( remainingTime < 3600 ) {
        TimerTextSize = 40
    } else {
        TimerTextSize = 20
    }
    return TimerTextSize;
}
```

My text component header looks like this (see update below for full timer code):

```
<Animated.Text style={{ fontSize: _____________, fontFamily: 'Arial',...>
    ...
</Animated.Text>
```

In the blank I have tried everything I can think of including: CalculateTimeSize(remainingTime), CalculateTimeSize({remainingTime}), {CalculateTimeSize(remainingTime)}, and {CalculateTimeSize({remainingTime})}

Clearly, from the way I'm throwing around curly braces, I just don't know what I'm doing. Thank you for any help you can provide.

*Update*
The full timer code for a better view of the CalculateTimeSize function call:

```
<CountdownCircleTimer
    isPlaying
    duration = { 65 }
    colors = { ColorScheme.Orange.e }
    onComplete = { () => {
        console.log('Timer expired')
        return [ true, 0 ]
    }}
>
    {({ remainingTime, animatedColor }) => (
        <Animated.Text style={{
            fontSize: {CalculateTimeSize(remainingTime)},
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }}>
            {FormatTime({ remainingTime })}
        </Animated.Text>
    )}
</CountdownCircleTimer>
```

Comment: Why are you passing the value to the function is it outside the specified component?? And there is no need to accept argument in curly brackets you can just specify arguments like in normal functions CalculateTimeSize = (remainingTime)

Comment: The remainingTime comes from the timer so the function knows what to do. Is it bad to not rename it within the function? I have added the full timer code for additional context. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please check out the answer and say if the problem still persists

Comment: Darshan, I greatly appreciate your help and the lesson on destructuring, however that was not the issue. To be honest, I don't know exactly what the issue was, but it now works. See my answer below if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate when this happens. I do have working code now, but I'm not sure what is different about it than what I previously had because I tried so many different things along the way. I will post the code below, but I will first comment on the extra curly braces that seemed to be confusing myself and Darshan.

I had the curly braces in there in the first place because the example code on the GitHub repo for the timer component had them (if you care to see: https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer/tree/master/packages/web#react-countdown-circle-timer). The code below works with them in place, and it does not work without them. Perhaps what is going on is in fact destructuring, as Darshan indicated, but I don't understand destructuring enough to say one way or the other. I do believe the curly braces has something to do with what the CountownCircleTimer is doing "behind the scenes". Again, I don't actually understand the component/programming-in-general enough to dig into it. All I know is I kept poking around at the code and eventually the following worked. I hope this helps someone at some point.

```
<CountdownCircleTimer
    isPlaying
    duration = { 65 }
    colors = { ColorScheme.Orange.e }
    size = { 175 }
    onComplete = { () => {
        console.log('Timer expired')
        return [ true, 0 ]
    }}
    size = { 175 }
    trailColor = { ColorScheme.Orange.j }
>
    {({ remainingTime, animatedColor }) => (
        <Animated.Text style = {{
            fontSize: CalculateTimeSize({ remainingTime }),
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }}>
            {FormatTime({ remainingTime })}
        </Animated.Text>
    )}
</CountdownCircleTimer>

CalculateTimeSize = ({ remainingTime }) => {
    let TimerTextSize
    if ( remainingTime < 11 ) {
        TimerTextSize = 90
    } else if( remainingTime < 60 ) {
        TimerTextSize = 75
    } else if( remainingTime < 3600 ) {
        TimerTextSize = 50
    } else {
        TimerTextSize = 35
    }
    return TimerTextSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to access a variable which was not present

This tries to [de-structure a key from json](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/). But while calling the function single value is passed

> CalculateTimeSize = ({ remainingTime }) => { ... }

Change the above to this so that you can access the actual value passed

```
CalculateTimeSize = (remainingTime) => {
    ...
}
```

Change the function call from font size to this because it might be giving uhh error. (Since when I tried calling function from your way in stylesheet it was giving error)

> fontSize: {CalculateTimeSize(remainingTime)},

```
...
<Animated.Text style={{
    fontSize: CalculateTimeSize(remainingTime),
    ...
}}>
    ...
</Animated.Text>
...
```